# Dropdown menu with item IDs in FluentUI/react-northstar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am currently trying to make a dropdown with help of the FluentUI/react-northstar Dropdown component. Unfortunately the `items` prop for this component only has a `string[]` for the rendered names in the dropdown, but I need a `key` as well.

I tried to achieve this by using `renderItem` to add a custom renderer:

```
<Dropdown
    renderItem = (Component: React.ElementType, props: any): React.ReactNode => {
      ...
      return <Component key={props.key} content={props.name} />;
    };
    items={dropDownMapper(displayTree[0], 0)}
    ...
/>
```

The `dropDownMapper` function returns an array of objects like this: `[{key: string, name: string}, ...]`

With this I am able to render the correct items inside my dropdown menu, but I am not able to interact with them. I've tried adding an `onClick` to `<Component/>`, but since I use the framework, I am not sure what the `<Dropdown/>` expects me to do when the item was clicked and the [documentation](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.51.3/components/dropdown/definition) isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to make it work by adding the properties "header" and "content" to the items:

```
[{key: string, name: string, header: string, content: string}, ...]
```

The Dropdown component will:

- use header and content to render the choices
- use header to render the selected item
- pass the selected object to the on change event handler

[Example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fluent-ui-example-forked-qv09v)